# Parsing SSRS Report XML on ReportServer Database

Tags: sql-server, xml, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

This is a top part of the report's XML:

```
<Report xmlns:rd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner" xmlns:cl="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2010/01/componentdefinition" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2010/01/reportdefinition">
  <AutoRefresh>0</AutoRefresh>
  <DataSources>
    <DataSource Name="DataSource1">
      <DataSourceReference>Live Data</DataSourceReference>
      <rd:SecurityType>None</rd:SecurityType>
      <rd:DataSourceID>827954ef-81fc-4a34-8f40-5354265d867b</rd:DataSourceID>
    </DataSource>
  </DataSources>
</Report>
```

What I'm trying to do is to get all instances of DataSources. After hours of battling I realised I have to use multiple namespaces and reference them before my select statement. This is my query now:

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition' AS ns, 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2010/01/componentdefinition' AS cl, 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner' AS rd)
SELECT
    c.*,
    CAST( CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), c.Content) AS XML),
    G.value('ns:DataSource[1]/rd:SecurityType[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS 'SecurityType',
    G.value('ns:DataSource[1]/ns:DataSourceReference[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS 'DataSourceReference',
    G.value('ns:DataSource[1]/rd:DataSourceID[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS 'DataSourceID'
FROM Catalog c
    OUTER APPLY (SELECT CAST( CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), c.Content) AS XML)) as Content(c)
    OUTER APPLY Content.c.nodes('//ns:DataSources') AS DS(G)
WHERE c.Type NOT IN (5, 4)
```

Now I am extremely puzzles as it works only with few XMLs. I know there is an other way to extract that info (I believe using `local-name()`) but I would like not only to make it work (any way possible) but also understand why it doesn't work in its current form (if it's not just lack of knowledge but SQL/XML restraint).

--edit: I used OUTER APPLY to get all the NULLs that do not work, once I know the query is spot on I would change it to CROSS

For comparison this is the beginning of the XML that the query returns the right values for:

```
<Report xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition" xmlns:rd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner">   
  <DataSources>
    <DataSource Name="DataSource1">
      <DataSourceReference>Live Data</DataSourceReference>
      <rd:SecurityType>None</rd:SecurityType>
      <rd:DataSourceID>956f67a3-7d7b-46cd-acb2-0e6490d0d33a</rd:DataSourceID>
    </DataSource>
  </DataSources>
```

I would be eternally grateful for any help understanding the above problem.

PS. I hate XML in SQL!

Comment: Define *doesn't work*.. I can't see any obvious problem with your query compared to the XML sample at the top

Comment: The results for G.value are NULL for the top one. Before I added namespaces they were NULL for all XMLs but no they are very selective

Comment: Post sample XML that demonstrates the problem i.e which the query returns NULL for

Comment: The top XML is the problem.. and all G.value columns return NULL

Answer (score 2):

Default namespace URI in the XML is :

```
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2010/01/reportdefinition"
```

while at the beginning of the query, you have a different URI mapped to the prefix `ns`:

```
'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition' AS ns
```

that's possibly the problem. In case you have different namespaces in different XML document, then you can't avoid ignoring the namespace by using `local-name()`, for example :

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2010/01/componentdefinition' AS cl, 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner' AS rd)
SELECT
    c.*,
    CAST( CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), c.Content) AS XML),
    G.value('*[local-name()="DataSource"][1]/rd:SecurityType[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS 'SecurityType',
    G.value('*[local-name()="DataSource"][1]/*[local-name()="DataSourceReference"][1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS 'DataSourceReference',
    G.value('*[local-name()="DataSource"][1]/rd:DataSourceID[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS 'DataSourceID'
FROM Catalog c
    OUTER APPLY (SELECT CAST( CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), c.Content) AS XML)) as Content(c)
    OUTER APPLY Content.c.nodes('//*[local-name()="DataSources"]') AS DS(G)
WHERE c.Type NOT IN (5, 4)
```

Comment: So if the Report is build using different versions of Report Builder etc. the schema for its XML will change? I thought it wouldn't matter since the XML definition would come from Reporting Services which uses 2008? Of course that is just my assumption, for which I would be very happy to receive clarification

Comment: Looks like so, that the different namespace comes from different version of SSRS. Though I'm not experienced SSRS guy to actually give clarification on this matter.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post but I am adding this to possible help someone who is stuck going down the path I have been treading for more than a year.  I have inherited an environment that has had little effort in maintenance and the report catalog has been growing since SQL 2000.  There is zero documentation and one of the challenges in moving forward was documenting what procedures are used in the more than 1,200 SSRS reports.  This means extracting the datasets and sources.  All SQL only solutions errored at odd points and left me with no complete solution for the task in front of me.  What I finally did was give up on doing it in SQL and wrote a little app in C# (you can do this with the Community version of VS2017).

Simplified flow:

1. Retrieve Report Name and rdl content (which is XML) from the Report Server DB via SqlClient.
2. Load each record into a small data container class.
3. Within the container safely convert the content to XML.
4. Search the XML Document nodes for the desired information.
5. Output those nodes To a small container class for display and export for inclusion in my Run Book.

My solution is in C# and a WPF UserControl.
The essential parts of the Controls XAML

```
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="27"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Button x:Name="btnFetchCat" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Margin="10,2,10,2" Content="Get 'em, Sparky" Click="BtnFetchCat_Click"/>
        <ListBox x:Name="lstReports" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" SelectionChanged="LstReports_SelectionChanged"/>
        <TreeView x:Name="tvwRptXML" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"/>
        <DataGrid x:Name="grdDS" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1"/>
    </Grid>
```

The Code behind for this control is

```
    public partial class usSQLrdlViewer : UserControl
    {
        #region Variables
        private SQLcxn _cn = new SQLcxn();
        private List<ReportDef> _lstRD = new List<ReportDef>();
        #endregion

        #region Class Maintenance
        public usSQLrdlViewer() { InitializeComponent();}
        #endregion

        #region Class Events
        private void BtnFetchCat_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection _cn = new SqlConnection();
            _cn.ConnectionString = "your connection string";
            try
            {
                _cn.Open();
                string _q = "SELECT TOP 25 Name, Content FROM Catalog Where NOT Content IS NULL order by ModifiedDate DESC";
                SqlCommand _cmd = new SqlCommand(_q,_cn);
                SqlDataReader _rdr = _cmd.ExecuteReader();
                lstReports.ItemsSource = null;

                SqlDataReader _rdr = _cn.GetData(_q);
                if (_rdr != null)
                {
                    if (_rdr.HasRows)
                    {
                        _lstRD = new List<ReportDef>();
                        ReportDef _tmp = new ReportDef();
                        while (_rdr.Read())
                        {
                            _tmp = new ReportDef();
                            _tmp.ReportName = _rdr.GetString(0);
                            _tmp.SetRawSQL((byte[]) _rdr.GetValue(1));
                            _lstRD.Add(_tmp);
                        }
                    }
                }
                lstReports.ItemsSource = _lstRD;
                FetchCommandText();
            }
            catch(ExceptionType ext) // trap with type as appropriate 
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Retrieve failed\n" + exp.ErrorMessage);
            }
        }
        private void LstReports_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if(lstReports.SelectedIndex >=0)
            {
                tvwRptXML.Items.Clear();
                ReportDef _sel = (ReportDef)lstReports.SelectedItem;
                TreeViewItem _tvi = new TreeViewItem();
                _tvi.Header = string.Format("Content for {0}", _sel.ReportName);
                tvwRptXML.Items.Add(_tvi);
                TraverseNodes(_sel.ContentAsDocument, _tvi);
                MessageBox.Show("Ready");
            }
        }
        #endregion

        #region Public Subs and Functions
        #endregion

        #region Private Subs and Functions
        private void FetchCommandText()
        {
            grdDS.ItemsSource = null;
            XmlNodeList _nl;
            XmlNode _sib ;
            List<QuickView> _qv = new List<QuickView>();
            QuickView _qt = null;
            foreach (ReportDef _rd in _lstRD)
            {
                _nl = _rd.ContentAsDocument.GetElementsByTagName("CommandText");
                for(int _fi = 0;_fi < _nl.Count;_fi++)
                {
                    _sib = _nl[_fi].ParentNode.FirstChild;
                    _qt = new QuickView();
                    _qt.ReportName = _rd.ReportName;
                    _qt.DataSetName = _nl[_fi].InnerText;
                    _qt.AdditionalInfo = string.Format("{0} [{1}]", _sib.InnerText, _sib.Name);
                    _qv.Add(_qt);
                }
            }
            grdDS.ItemsSource = _qv;
        }
        private void TraverseNodes(XmlNode _xn, TreeViewItem _oTVI)
        {
            // cover this node assuming the passed in node is populated
            TreeViewItem _tti = new TreeViewItem();
            foreach (XmlNode _cNd in _xn.ChildNodes)
            {
                _tti = new TreeViewItem();
                if (_cNd.HasChildNodes)
                {
                    _tti.Header = string.Format("Name: {0} [Type: {1}]", _cNd.Name, _cNd.NodeType.ToString());
                    TraverseNodes(_cNd, _tti);
                }
                else
                {
                    _tti.Header = string.Format("Name {2} [Type: {0}] Value: {1}", _cNd.NodeType.ToString(), _cNd.Value, _cNd.Name);
                }
                _oTVI.Items.Add(_tti);
            }
        }
        #endregion
    }
```

The first of the helper files is used as a display container and the vehicle for converting the Content field (Image type in SQL or SQLBytes in the .NET Type).  This class code

```
   public class ReportDef
    {
        #region Variables
        private string _nm = "";
        private object _rawSQL = null;
        private byte[] _rawByt = null;
        private string _rawDoc = "";
        private XmlDocument _xDoc = null;
        #endregion

        #region Properties
        public string ReportName { get { return _nm; } set { _nm = value; } }
        public object RawSQLData { get { return _rawSQL; } set { _rawSQL = value; } }
        public byte[] ContentasByteArray { get { return _rawByt; } set { _rawByt = value; } }
        public string ContentAsString { get { return _rawDoc; } set { _rawDoc = value; } }
        public XmlDocument ContentAsDocument { get { return _xDoc; } set { _xDoc = value; } }
        public override string ToString() { return _nm;}
        #endregion

        #region Class Maintenance
        public ReportDef() { }
        #endregion


        #region Public Subs and Functions
        public void SetRawSQL(object _content)
        {
            if (_content != null)
            {
                _rawSQL = _content;
            }
            if (_rawSQL != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    _rawByt = (byte[])_rawSQL;
                    _rawDoc = Convert.ToBase64String(_rawByt, 0, _rawByt.Length);
                    // now to make the XML
                    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(_rawByt))
                    using (StreamReader _rdr = new StreamReader(ms))
                    {
                        while ((!_rdr.EndOfStream) && (_rdr.Peek() > -1) && ((char)_rdr.Peek() != '<'))
                        {
                            _rdr.Read();
                        }
                        if (!_rdr.EndOfStream)
                        {
                            _xDoc = new XmlDocument();
                            _xDoc.Load(_rdr);
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Failed to convert {1} error {2}", _nm, ex.Message));
                }
             }
       }
        #endregion

    }
```

The final class is a simple data container.  I am only including the essential parts of the class as I have enriched it for my particular purposes.

```
   public class QuickView
    {
        #region Variables
        private string _rn = "";
        private string _ds = "";
        private string _add = "";
        #endregion

        #region Properties
        public string ReportName { get { return _rn; } set { _rn = value; } }
        public string DataSetName { get { return _ds; } set { _ds = value; } }
        public string AdditionalInfo { get { return _add; } set { _add = value; } }

        #endregion

        #region Class Maintenance
        public QuickView(){ }
        #endregion
   }
```

I opted not to include an image of the app as it is difficult to do so without including potentially protected information.

In the result you have three columns.

1. Left to right it includes a ListBox that you can search, sort and
   select.
2. A TreeView that does not include all the node types in the display which can easily be extended to export any of the elements of sections of the tree.  This is populated by selecting an item in the ListBox.
3. A DataGrid with three columns listing the Report Name, the datasource(s) used in the report and the command Text for each datasource.

This framework works with ALL of the reports in our report server catalog and I have also used it to import from .rdl files and create reports on the fly via code.

Hope this helps someone else faced with similar challenges to mine and meets the guidelines for SO.  Many thanks to the dozens of SO contributors who contributed pieces this solution.